# How to copy and paste rows with filtering and hidden columns?

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to copy and paste a certain row in a spreadsheet that has filtering and some hidden columns. For some reason, when my filtering is on, Excel doesn't copy the hidden columns and when I paste the row, it is omitting the hidden columns.

Is there any workaround for this problem? Maybe a secret shortcut that copies all cells in selection, including hidden ones?

Thanks.

Comment: Do you need those columns to remain hidden after the copy?`

Comment: yes, that's part of the problem. By the way, tried to change the column width to 0.1 - it's working, but my spreadsheet has hundreds of columns, so it's not so efficient.

Answer (score 1):

Easy solution here (You could also loop through the sheet and store indexes of hidden columns, but I think that might actually take more time than making this copied sheet)

```
Sub CopyHiddenColumns()

    Dim DestinationSheet As Worksheet, TempSheet As Worksheet, CopySheet As Worksheet
    Set DestinationSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("DestSheet")
    Set CopySheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("CopySheet")
    CopySheet.Copy Before:=ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1)
    Set TempSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1)

    TempSheet.UsedRange.Hidden = False
    TempSheet.UsedRange.Copy Destination:= DestinationSheet.Range("A1")
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    TempSheet.Delete
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End Sub
```

Obviously, you can use specified ranges rather than `UsedRange` and `Range("A1")`.  I just placed those as fillers to allow the code to compile

Comment: Hi, it seems that there's an error with "Set TempSheet = ..." row - syntax error.

Comment: @Lev sorry.  silly mistake (I make all the time with copying sheets).  The code is editted to fix that now

Comment: please see my solution, based on your answer. Let me know what you think.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to RGA, I played a bit more with his code, and got this result. Works fine, what do you think?

```
   Sub lev()
Dim ws As Worksheet, temp As Worksheet, copyrange As Range, pasterange As Range

Set ws = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet

 On Error GoTo nocell

Set copyrange = Application.InputBox(Prompt:="Please Select Range", Title:="Range Select", Type:=8)

On Error GoTo nocell

Set pasterange = Application.InputBox(Prompt:="Please Select ONE Cell to paste the your selection!", Title:="Range Select", Type:=8)
On Error GoTo 0

ws.Copy before:=ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet

ActiveSheet.Name = "temp123"
Range("a1", Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
    Selection.EntireColumn.Hidden = False

    Range("a1", Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Selection.EntireRow.Hidden = False

    Range(copyrange.Address()).Select

Selection.Copy Destination:=pasterange
 Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Sheets("temp123").Delete
Application.DisplayAlerts = True

nocell:
End Sub
```

This code can handle both filtering, hidden rows and hidden columns.
Actually, this is super cool and useful.

Please let me know what you think!